# Pushforward of Lebesgue measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Calculate pushforward of Lebesgue measure on interval $(0, \infty)$ along function $h$ defined as $h(x) = x - 2^n$ for $2^n \leq x < 2^{n+1}, n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Is it absolute continuous regardless of Lebesgue measure? If it is, i have to calculate its Radon-Nikody derivative.
Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please ask about your specific problem, state what you do and what you do not understand. Don't take the downvote personally, it is about the question. http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That is the problem i got i my exam, I don't really know where to start, because of that I wrote the whole text i got. I know i should be more specific but i don't really know how to be in this case.

Comment: $h$ is not defined on (0,1), is this on purpose?

Comment: The way you've defined $h$ is that it is a sequence of functions so it should be $h_{n}$. It also looks like this sequence of functions should be defined piecewise. Maybe take a closer look problem and edit your question.